# Sails.js : findOne() works but not find() in Waterline

Tags: node.js, orm, model, sails.js, waterline

I am developing a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) app with `MySQL`. I have a model, for which create and retrieve work without any problems.

```
 Model.findOne({ where: { someAttribute : 'foo' }, function(err, model) {
  // some logic
});
```

works fine, but not

```
Model.find({ where: { someAttribute : 'foo' }, function(err, model) {
  // some logic
});
```

`Model.find(...)` always returns an empty array. I have multiple records on the model which satisfy the where clause condition.

Comment: It should work as expected. I would re-check or post more specific code.

Comment: This isn't even valid Javascript syntax: `find({ where: { someAttribute : 'foo' }, function` so you're obviously not posting your exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Given code should cause error! It is not even in valid format. It should be

```
Model.findOne({ where: { someAttribute : 'foo' }}).exec(function(err, model) {
    // some logic
});

Model.find({ where: { someAttribute : 'foo' }}).exec(function(err, model) {
    // some logic
});
```

Update your code to clarify your question.